# Make an iOS App to invoke Command Lines with a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jailbreak

I was making an app to call system commands after pressing a button.

The environment is Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5, Xcode 8.3.3, Objective-C.

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *title = [sender titleForState: UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *plainText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ button pressed", title];
    _statusLabel.text = plainText;

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath : @"/bin/ls"];
    NSArray *arguments;
    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-l", @"-a", @"-t", nil];
    [task setArguments : arguments];
    [task setStandardOutput : pipe];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                               encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog (@"woop!  got\n%@", string);
}
```

I run this on my jailbroken iPhone 6 (iOS version 10.2). The program always crashes when I press the button.

The crash log is:

```
    2017-07-13 14:08:20.346060 Hello World[2770:532052] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't posix_spawn: error 1'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x18ae451b8 0x18987c55c 0x18ae45100 0x18b96de6c 0x1000d646c 0x190d2fd30 0x190d2fcb0 0x190d1a128 0x190d2f59c 0x190d2f0c4 0x190d2a328 0x190cfada0 0x1914e475c 0x1914de130 0x18adf2b5c 0x18adf24a4 0x18adf00a4 0x18ad1e2b8 0x18c7d2198 0x190d657fc 0x190d60534 0x1000d69c8 0x189d015b8)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

I don't know **'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't posix_spawn: error 1'**.

Also, the final command I want to test is

```
kill -USR1 `ps ax|grep omm|grep ys|xargs|cut -d ' '-f 1`
```

However, the commands above just cannot work, I can't move on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bottom line: Running commands from a sandboxed app isn't possible, because that's the purpose of the Sandbox. You'll have to install your app the jailbroken way, in `/Applications` for it to be unsandboxed.

Comment: @Siguza Thanks a lot. But I don't fully understand. You mean I made my App installed in wrong place? What should I do to install my app in `/Applications`?

Comment: @Siguza How can I install the App out of Sandbox?

Comment: For yourself: Just copy the `.app` folder there. For deployment with Cydia/APT: Google `dpkg-deb`.

Comment: @Siguza Thank you. I just found  `.app` file in my Mac. Where can I find the folder?

Comment: That _is_ the folder (Finder is just annoying, right click > show contents).

Comment: @Siguza I finished copying. But the icon of App doesn't appear on the DESKTOP. That means I have installed the App to the iPhone? How can I run it?